# for /f: Read input with various delimiters

Tags: batch-file, variables, for-loop, text-files

I am using GPG (or 7-Zip) to generate hashsums of files. I want to read these hashsums to variables in a batch file to work with them further.

My problem is that GPG creates -based on path length and chosen hashalgo- different output:

SHA256, short path:

```
c:\test.txt: E3B0C442 98FC1C14 9AFBF4C8 996FB924 27AE41E4 649B934C A495991B
         7852B855
```

MD5, short path:

```
c:\test.txt: D4 1D 8C D9 8F 00 B2 04  E9 80 09 98 EC F8 42 7E
```

SHA256, long path:

```
C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Testfile-longname.ext1.txt: 
764B2054 853B6BCC 919853DD D47F4A3A F5A2DFB1 A5EE6967 52051E1E 12B143CC
```

7-zip gives the following output when using CRC32 and SHA256 for a file:

```
7-Zip (a) [64] 16.04 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-10-04
Scanning
1 file, 296533469 bytes (283 MiB)
CRC32    SHA256                                                           Size           Name
-------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- -------------  ------------
BB280EC2 22B8AB1B1AD2F04A47BFD409997A834B30C617B619522381123B7D2AD8F724F9 123456789      Testfile-longname.ext1.txt
-------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- -------------  ------------
BB280EC2 22B8AB1B1AD2F04A47BFD409997A834B30C617B619522381123B7D2AD8F724F9     296533469  
Size: 123456789
CRC32  for data:              BB280EC2
SHA256 for data:              22B8AB1B1AD2F04A47BFD409997A834B30C617B619522381123B7D2AD8F724F9
```

Unfortunately I can not make any predictions about path length and hashalgo used, but I can say which program is used (GPG or 7-zip).

I tried various settings in delims and tokens for for /f but was unable to catch MD5 and SHA256 reliably in GPGs output and CRC32 (and perhaps SHA256) in 7-zips output.

Thanks for any help!

Clarification:
With GPG I have the problem with the different output formats where I am unable to get just the checksum.
When using 7-ZIP I am uable to extract the checksums from the large (unimportant) parts of the output.

Comment: so you have a problem with both GPG _and_ 7-zip ? or just GPG? can you [edit] your question to show input/output in each case? and maybe also your attempts since you seem to have tried things.

Comment: I would use the built-in tool `certutil` to get the checksum instead. The value is always on the second line of the output.

Comment: If you want to use GPG, you can scan for the second colon, then append everything after to get the hash value...

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre : You are right, I have added some information above.

Comment: @SomethingDark : I need 7-ZIP and GPG in other parts of the batch so they are present, whereas I am unsure whether certutil is available on all versions of Windows with the same output and hashalgorithms.

Comment: @aschipfl : The second colon... I totally missed that when searching for apropiate delimiters. Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example of output you gave, try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=: " %a in ('type foobar.txt ^| findstr "data"') do echo %d
```

where foobar.txt contains the output of your command, you could replace type foobar.txt with the command.

Comment: Two problems: 1) test-full.sha256 contains 7-ZIPs output. While type c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\test-full.sha256 | findstr "data" works in command-prompt type c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\test-full.sha256 ^| findstr "data" used in a batchfile displays the contents of test-full.sha256 as output but then says "Syntax for filename, directory name, ... is wrong". So the findstr-part of the pipe is not working.

Comment: 2) Used in a batchfile for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=: " %a in ('type c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\test-full.sha256 ^| findstr "data"') do echo %d results in this error: "\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\test-full.sha256 can not be used syntctically at this point." (so c: is missing) Have I missed or messed up some escape characters? PS: Sorry, I have to try to translate the errormessages.

Comment: 1) the ^ is to escape the pipe for use in a for loop, dont include it in a test batch file outside of the loop.

Comment: 2) in a batch file, you must double the %'s so %a becomes %%a and %d beomes %%d

Comment: Thanks, now it works! I hope I will stop making these mistakes with escape-characters one day...

Comment: took me years :) this isn't what they made batch for, but i love it anyway :)